How Ready for a 2031 TEL ban Is The Avgas-Fueled Fleet?
Per this article on AvWeb, California has codified a full-on cold-turkey ban on leaded avgas effective January 1st, 2031.
Obviously there's more than six years between now and then, but what is there left to do for the avgas-fueled fleet to be unleaded-ready by then - as of today (October 2nd, 2024)?
What proactive measures can pilots and owners take to ensure their operations aren't disrupted?

The article also says "But if the FAA misses that deadline, the bill, as passed, will still ban leaded avgas the next day."

@PeterGreen: GAMI already proposes G100UL for TEL-free fuel compatible with 100LL engines (in addition of 94UL and 91UL which can also be used in many 100LL engines with an adapter), and EU has already planned to completely sunset TEL in may 2025 for any fuel, 5 years before FAA. Anyway if there were no solutions, then the bill would just be repealed.

@mins Not California. They'll ban piston planes first.

@mins -- California could just yanno, start buying G100UL directly by the tankcarload and shipping it out to airports themselves lol

@UnrecognizedFallingObject: It seems they already planned for a distributor "GAMI partnered with Avfuel Corporation through Avfuel Technology Initiatives Corporation (ATIC) to oversee logistics and distribution. Avfuel is a global supplier of aviation fuels and services, and currently sells 100LL to more than 675 FBOs" (source)

@user71659: "Not California. They'll ban piston planes first". You could be wrong: Aircraft operators in California will likely be the first to be able to fill their tanks with unleaded 100 octane aviation fuel and that will be GAMI fuel.

@mins -- it seems that 94UL is the closest thing available so far if Livermore's fuel selection is indicative

@UnrecognizedFallingObject: If you read the article: "The phase out of lead won’t be complete until 100UL is available everywhere 100LL is sold today; that rollout process will probably take several years.". Hopefully this will be less than 5 years. See also the paragraph "Will 100LL be banned before G100UL is widely available?"

@mins -- the article you linked is from Feb.

The fleet is 100% ready, because the point of a drop-in replacement is that it can be used as a substitute without any modifications whatsoever. It's not the fleet that has to be ready, it's the fuel which has been the tricky part. At this point the status of the readiness for the drop-in replacement is debatable and I will not go over it here, although I would say that the available options would seem to fit the bill for the vast majority of engines.
Having a fuel formulated and tested is one thing, having it mass-produced and distributed is another, what pilots and owners can do (no matter where they are) is pressure governments to get their acts together, and where the bans are going to be in place to make sure their local airfield operators are on the ball on getting the fuel.

Yeah, G100UL seems to be more or less a drop-in substitute for most aircraft AFAIK (the STC is paperwork and placarding, similar to a Peterson mogas STC, at least AIUI).  The problem is actually getting your hands on a 55gal drum of the stuff, as the distribution chain seems to not want to touch it with a 10' pole.
